# JSON SQL Server 2016 parse

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016, open-json

I have a nested JSON as output form a form and I need to parse it in order to send it in joined tables. I cannot parse some of the data I have in the JSON: labels, rangesValues or body I get NULL
anyone encountered this type?

```
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = '{
   "Id":"712db489",
   "label":"kjk",
   "ranges":{
      "rangeQuestion":null,
      "minRange":0,
      "maxRange":10,
      "rangeValues":[1,2],
      "hasMarks":false
   },
   "labels":[1,2],
   "options":[
      {
         "body":"Yes",
         "sequence":1
      },
      {
         "body":"No",
         "sequence":2
      }
   ]
}'

SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              label   nvarchar(250), --ok
              maxRange   nvarchar(250) '$.ranges.maxRange', --ok
              labels   nvarchar(250), -- not parsed
              rangesValues nvarchar(250) '$.ranges.rangeValues' , -- not parsed
              body   nvarchar(250) '$.options.body' -- not parsed

 )
```

the output should be like

minRange maxRange rangeValues
0                     10                 1
0                     10                 2

body    sequence

Yes        1

No         2

And what can be done if there are 3 levels nested?

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json = '{
   "Id":"712db489",
   "label":"kjk",
   "ranges":{
      "rangeQuestion":null,
      "minRange":0,
      "maxRange":10,
      "rangeValues": [
                {
                    "rangeValue": 1,
                    "otherValue": 10
                },
                {
                    "rangeValue": 2,
                    "otherValue": 20
                }
            ],
      "hasMarks":false
   },
   "labels":[1,2],
   "options":[
      {
         "body":"Yes",
         "sequence":1
      },
      {
         "body":"No",
         "sequence":2
      }
   ]
}'

SELECT r.minRange,
       r.maxRange,
       rV.[value] AS rangeValue
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.ranges')  
     WITH (minRange int,
           maxRange int,
           rangeValues nvarchar(MAX) 
           AS JSON) r
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (r.rangeValues) rV;
```

Comment: What are you expecting back here? `$.ranges.maxRange` has an array value in it, for example `[1,2]`. Are you expecting the array, `1`, `2` or 2 rows (with the values `1` and `2`)? The others that have "failed" too are the same. Please do show us the expected results you are after.

Comment: maxRange is returning ok, but labels as I have a mix of arrays as [1,2] and also other objects like options I would need to get them in separate rows

minRange maxRange rangeValues   
0                     10                 1         
0                     10                 2       
   
body    sequence
Yes        1
No         2

Comment: So show us the results you expect. Does `1` relate to `Yes` or `No`, for example?

Comment: in the case of options 1 is related to yes, and 2 to no

Comment: So you want 2 datasets? Why isn't `label` in either, when it is in your attempt?

Comment: options and ranges I want to send them in separate tables

Comment: Then you need multiple queries.

Comment: yes, It may be this case, so to get the options in one query and ranges in another one. One example of how to do it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like, from the discussion in the comments, what you are actually after is this:

```
SELECT r.minRange,
       r.maxRange,
       rV.[value] AS rangeValue
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.ranges')  
     WITH (minRange int,
           maxRange int,
           rangeValues nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) r
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (r.rangeValues) rV;

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@json,'$.options')
     WITH (body varchar(3),
           sequence int) o;
```

Comment: it works! I saw in some examples the cross apply but I did not used it. thank you

Comment: When I have 3 nested levels how I can extract the value to the last level? The difference is that is not an array but an object at 3rd level

Comment: Sounds like you should be asking another question, @drcz .

Answer (score 0):

second question I solved with

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json = '{
   "Id":"712db489",
   "label":"kjk",
   "ranges":{
      "rangeQuestion":null,
      "minRange":0,
      "maxRange":10,
      "rangeValues": [
                {
                    "rangeValue": 1,
                    "otherValue": 10
                },
                {
                    "rangeValue": 2,
                    "otherValue": 20
                }
            ],
      "hasMarks":false
   },
   "labels":[1,2],
   "options":[
      {
         "body":"Yes",
         "sequence":1
      },
      {
         "body":"No",
         "sequence":2
      }
   ]
}'

SELECT ranges.minRange as minRange,
       ranges.maxRange as maxRange,
       rangeValues.rangeValue AS rangeValue
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.ranges')  
WITH (minRange int,
    maxRange int,
    rangeValues nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON
    ) as ranges
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (ranges.rangeValues) 
with (
rangeValue int ,
otherValue int
)as rangeValues;
```